# Visual studio 2008 adds inline style instead of changing markup

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

Visual studio 2008 on dragging (say) a td inside a table adds a inline style named style1,style2, and so on......while this might be good thing for some purposes it is just better to have a style="height:80px;" added to the markup of the TD...

is there any way to make VS 2008 not add inline styles and add into the markup of the element.....????

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you wanting to know if you can stop Visual Studio from adding in styles to control the display of a table cell? You would like to have <td height=80></td> instead?

Comment: yes...it would be better though if it can add it the css way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out so i thought i would post it here...

to stop VS 2008 from adding css styles to the page you can turn it off from the **Style Application** toolbar and set it to manual or customise it according to your wish